# AWS get lists of missed objects from elastic cache metrics

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

It is possible to log list of misses objects from elastic cache (Memcache)? Is there lambda function to log the missed objects?

Comment: What do you use in Elasticache ? Redis ?

Comment: @Ersoy I am using Memcache

Comment: I would provide Redis related solutions for this, sorry not familiar with Memcache.